# Some way or place to post "tips"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Is there a way or place to post general tips that other SO users might find useful? Obviously they wouldn't be questions and would have no answers and probably no related discussion (CW doesn't seem to apply).

Edit:
To clarify: I meant general programming tips, not SO related ones.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - removing my suggestion!

Comment: "Discussion" seems more appropriate in this case, but I can't remove your message about re-tagging

Answer (score 4):

You can at any time play what I would call SO Jeopardy, if you want to do something like that. Come up with a question that is answered by the tip, ask it, and answer it yourself. This is a Q&A page, and that would be the way to do it. It has been encouraged several times in the podcasts too.

As for tips about the site itself, there is SOFAQ here in meta and the FAQ.