# Is it possible to share a tip on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Some way or place to post “tips”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10642/some-way-or-place-to-post-tips)
>   [Pseudo reversed concept for stackoverflow site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21517/pseudo-reversed-concept-for-stackoverflow-site)

I've found a great python tip that I couldn't find on stackoverflow with google (I got the tip on freenode). Is it possible to share it on stackoverflow, so that other people can benefit?

Comment: Sure, just ask the question that your tip solves, then answer it yourself.  Who knows, maybe someone else will post an even better solution.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21517/pseudo-reversed-concept-for-stackoverflow-site - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10642/some-way-or-place-to-post-tips

Answer (score 3):

I suggest two alternatives, although I am sure there are more ...

1- Create a question, include the tip, and ask the community for feedback on the tip and to suggest alternatives.  If someone suggests a better alternative, accept it!

2- Ask the question, then add an answer with the tip.  Some might interpret this as trolling for rep; I am on the fence.

Comment: Speaking from experience, I don't believe you get *any* rep points for answering your own question.

Comment: I haven't tried, but I presume that you get rep if your answer is voted up by others, even if you asked the question.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @tomjedrz: you are correct. That is the reason that some people CW their answers to their own questions.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, think Jeopardy.

Additionally, the typical way to do this is that you do not mark your answer as the accepted answer unless it also gets the most votes, and mark your answer (but not the question) as community wiki to avoid the appearance of begging rep and still allow others who contribute to earn it for their answers (and you can still get rep for the question itself).

Answer (score 2):

Ask it like on Jeopardy.

Comment: The first person to link a "thinking music" MP3 into their question is going to get a visit from Mr Ty Cobb.

Comment: Could you explain? I'm not from the US.